# Creating a pen and paper template from a spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I work with teams that go to sites and audit compliance.

I have a spreadsheet with columns of data -

Functional Area - Policy Citation - Question # - Question Text

What I want to do is push/pull this data into a word template. Most of it is going to be up/down formatted. So it'll look like it does in Excel.

Some of questions are set up with the question on the vertical axis and multiple columns across the horizontal axis. These are formatted different.

Stuff like "Check five areas for XZY" So I'd have five columns and one row for each question.

I want to keep a source document - my spreadsheet, so I can give each questions a unique identifier to track it throughout the year as we go to each site. I need to do this because as we work through things, my checklists might change a little. A question might flow better if asked earlier or later, so we'll move it. But when we're all said and done I still need to be able to see all the answers across all the sites for that specific question.

The last complication is that my team fills these out in the field with pen on paper, then enters in the info into the electornic version. Prior to this they did this into the word document that generated the printable form. Then I would manually take that data and put it into a spread sheet. I'm trying to avoid this.

My temptation is to format all this in Excel, but I worry that it will become Excel abuse. I'd rather use my source document to generate a word document. But I'm at a loss. I looked at mail merging - but I have hundreds of questions. HUNDREDS. And without it dynamically generating the document I'd have to manually build it. I'd like to avoid that.

I'm open to ideas... even if I get dialed in so I'm at least hitting the paper target here I'd be happy.

Comment: With Office 365 it is possible to design the form in PowerApps. The field user enters the data into the app running on a phone or tablet and the data is stored in Excel, SharePoint, etc, and can be retrieved from there for analysis. Is this an option for you?

Comment: @teylyn Unfortunately it isn't. High security areas. No phones, no tablets. Low tech business - No Office 365.

But man that does sound sweet.